# AKKA Persistent Actor

Tags: scala, akka, event-sourcing

> 1 - Can someone explain, why in AKKA Persistent Actors, updating the
>   state is done after its event is recorded ?
>
> 1.1 - What would happen if before the update state "callback" happen, the system crash ?

*(I think I kind of get it but my confusion comes from how i am not able to understand the handling of a **Command**. I don't see it as something different from handling an **Event**. see below)*

> 2 - Is there a difference between the execution/handling of a Command
>   and the "update state callBack" which is to be related to the handling
>   of an event.
>
> 2.1 - In other words, where should go the handling of the Command, and where should go the handling of the event. Are those two "handlings"
>   necessarily different.

All the examples that i have seen mostly shows that there is nothing specific about handling a command other than validating it and then persisting its associated event and updating the actor state accordingly.

This means that handling a command is somewhat handling an event after all. This means that the vent can't be recor

My confusion comes the fact that, an event can only record something that has happened. But in all the examples that i have seen, upon receiving a command, nothing particular happens, if it is just actually, setting the event that the action was executed (which one ?) and then updating the state. This somewhat reverse the logic of things.

If the command is create an order, then we would have automatically, probably after validation, that an order_was_created, and then after an updated state function that would update the state of the actor according to the event receive.

It just feels strange. SO in a sense, a Command, aside from being validated, never triggers anything, especially if it has to do with updating something, but place an event which then will trigger the real work.

> So a Command is here to simply say if an event as happened, where this
>   event will actually made a reality after. That is, it is done after for recovery purpose.

It is confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A command is a request to change data. An event is an applied change and after the fact. Changes to data are validated prior to journaling the event. A journaled event is considered a guaranteed successful update because it is persisted after validations have been applied. When the persistent actor rehydrates, it replays all the changes and the state is updated accordingly with the guarantee that all updates can be applied. This is the basic reason why the state is applied afterwards. The pattern you are seeing is known as Event Sourcing. I think this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/ktoso/akka-persistence-event-sourcing-in-30-minutes) explains it well.

Answer (score 1):

The recent (Dec. 2016) article "[Akka event sourcing done right](https://web.archive.org/web/20221128145647/http://filippodeluca.com/programming/2016/12/09/akka-eventsourcing-done-right) " by [Filippo De Luca](https://twitter.com/FilippoDeLuca) proposes an alternative to the usual workflow, which (the usual workflow) is:

> The persistent actor flow looks like this usually:
>
> - A Command is Received by the Actor
> - The Command is translated into an Event based on the Actor's status.
> - The Event is persisted
> - The Actor status is modified in response to the event
>
> This flow has a major drawback in the 2nd step. If the logic of translating this Command (or the Stimulus) is bugged the original intention is lost.

But Filippo offers another perspective:

> In the application I am working at the moment, a persistent Actor is responding to some external events received from a bunch of Kafka topics. These events are transformed into local events before persisting them. This transformation, that depends on the current Actor status, contains a lot of business rules that can change in the future.
> A bug in this logic makes the whole event sourcing architecture pointless.
>
> I think that a much better model is to apply this logic after the event has been persisted:
>
> - A Command is Received by the Actor
> - The Command is persisted
> - The Command is applied to the Actor status, that is modified.
>
> What I am proposing is to drop the 2nd step completely and treat the external Command as an Event, storing it in the Journal. In this case, even if we have a bug in the code that applies the command to the status, we can fix it and, it will be applied retroactively

However, Renato Cavlacanti comments

> > In the context of CQRS, a Domain Event is NOT a stimulus. It only express that something have happened that has some business value for your Domain.
> > An Event can be interpreted and trigger some other actions. In that case, it can be seen as a stimulus, but it's not it's first intent.
> >
> > Regarding the idea of Command Sourcing, it can be done but it's applicability is limited. **The main reason being that the command handlers must be pure. There must be no side effect**, no remote calls, no IO, no nothing. Just pure function call against your aggregate data. This is because you want to re-play them and get the same results.

Filippo recognizes:

> You got the point: in our scenario most of the Commands are actually Events sent by another service. We store them and then we apply changes to our model. The way we apply the changes may vary depending of the business requirement. But of course they cannot be rejected and need to be persisted anyway.
>
> I agree they are not Commands, they are external Events.
>
> I also would say we may want to reject a Command instead (and we do) without persisting anything.

Comment: The article by Filippo de Luca does not exist anymore. I found a [snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20221128145647/http://filippodeluca.com/programming/2016/12/09/akka-eventsourcing-done-right) at web.archive.org.